# How to stop running a suite if previously executed suite fails in protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor with jasmine framework. I need solution to stop the execution of running the suite if previous suite fails.

I have three set of test suites as below:
1. Health check - Tests all the web services are returning 200 response.
2. Smoke test - Checks the basic features of front end are looking good.
3. Regression test - Tests all the features.

My requirement is, If health check test case fails then do not run smoke test cases.

This can be achieved through following two ways:
1. Jenkins
2. Using process.exit(1) in the script

But, these two are not fit to my need.

Is there any way to achieve my need through protractor or jasmine way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it using several scripts in `package.json`. For example:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "health": "launch here only health",
    "smoke": "launch here only smoke",
    "regression": "launch here only regression",
    "test": "npm run health && npm run smoke && npm run regression",
  },
  ...
```

You will launch all tests using `npm run test`. If in some command appears error the others will not be execute.

Comment: pakcage.json is a shared one between dev and test. So, I cannot update it. Can I have something to be done from config file itself?

Comment: if it is shared why you can not update it? You have the same right as dev. I don't like struggle with strange requests, sorry.